# 0 getting truncated in DT_WSTR to DT_STR conversion

Tags: ssis

I am new to SSIS and facing below issue.

Records are being exported from sql server table to flat text file in SSIS.
In table,the column "ABC" is `nvarchar(32) not null` and it has one of the value 016

In the SSIS mapping from table to Flat file is: `DT_WSTR(32) to DT_STR(50)`

After export, 016 is exported as 16 in text file.
Can you please suggest why the 0 gets truncated and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the datatypes in the Data Flow Path -> Metadata if you changed the source and or destination datatype.
SSIS doesn't always adjust the Data Flow Path Metadata when changing the source or destination datatypes.

Make sure the Data type is set to DT_STR instead of INT (INT will remove leading 0's)

The only way to fix this is to rebuild the Data Flow Path (as far as i know)

I recently had the same issue.